# Dynamically adding event listener. Function fires but how can I send a variable parameter?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm building a table in JavaScript and it contains a cell with a link in it, which when clicked, should fire a function. The cell is being added in a loop, in which `i` is incremented with each cycle and I want embed `i` in my function as a parameter.

Using the code below, when I `alert(i);` in the receiving function, I'm not getting the correct number. For one thing, elements added regardless of the iteration, all have the number `3` (probably not co-incidentally, I am testing this on a 3 record data-source).

The code

```
// Add supplier name to cell as a link
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(data[i].supName);
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "Click to create a purchase order.";
a.href = "#";
alert('inserting '+i); // diagnostic line
a.onclick = function(){postData ('main/createPO.php', '', 'makePO(resp,'+i+')', '', '')};
td1.appendChild(a);
tr.appendChild(td1);
```

The above is in a `for` loop where the `i` is incremented.

The diagnostic alert, fires:

```
inserting 0
inserting 1
inserting 2
```

... but the embedded `i` always seems to be 3!

This is the important line:

```
a.onclick = function(){postData ('main/createPO.php', '', 'makePO(resp,'+i+')', '', '')};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This person had the same problem as you, and there's a good answer for it:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Well done. I missed that because I didn't understand the term in the title `closure`. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to get around your issue. I had a more complicated version of this problem.

for each  element, just make a custom attribute.

$(a).attr("myValue", i);

Then on .click, just pass Number($(this).attr("myValue"));

Comment: Thanks, but I try to avoid jQuery where possible, especially wnen in loops, because of the over-head. Interesting alternative though.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head how to do the equivalent without jQuery, but I'm positive there's a way to do this do custom attributes with simple JS (it might not be as simple as a.myValue = i, but it should be something like that).

Comment: The answer I accepted worked fine. The solution was quite well described on the post linked to.